Proguard crashes Firebase ML Kit SDK

I am facing crash using a third party library. The library uses Firebase ML Kit internally . I keep below classes in dexguard but still facing crash.

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**{*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.auth.** { *; }

Also tried
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { native <methods>; }

Crash on Release
(com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetectorV2Jni.zza+30)
      #17 pc 000000000371a674  /data/app/~~qwhDhLgDBZQo24gzlG7-nw==/com.wallet.zindigi-aTvg_3WxolipoPAKqugk4A==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.google.android.gms.vision.face.NativeFaceDetectorV2Impl.<init>+380)
(com.google.android.gms.vision.face.NativeFaceDetectorV2Creator.zza+48)
(com.google.android.gms.vision.face.ChimeraNativeBaseFaceDetectorCreator.newFaceDetector+40)
(com.google.android.gms.vision.face.internal.client.zzb.zza+78)
(com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzs.zzr+236)
(com.google.android.gms.vision.face.internal.client.zzb.<init>+18)
(com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector$Builder.build+78)
(com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzsp.zzow+78)

What am I missing?
